# При запуске python кода в CMD запускает редактор visual studio code

Tags: python, windows

[image: cmd]

Без каких либо ошибок запускает редактор ранее хотел переустановить `python` и вроде бы установил правильно поставил галочку `на add to path` перезагрузил пк и заметил, что код в папке не обозначен значком `python`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Решено! В файле кода не было python как способ открытия из-за того что сразу после установки надо было перезапустить ПК, после перезапуска в файле кода вышел python как способ открытия.

Answer (score 0):

Так изначально у вас неверный запуск. Команда общем случае должна выглядеть так

```console
...user> python G:\path\to\file\aiogram_bot.py
```